Is there a deterministic algorithm that operates in time $2^{O(\log^c(n))}$?
I am following the book, Theory of Computational Complexity, 2nd Edition Ding-Zhu Du, Ker-I Ko.
I am copying following text from the book,
Recently an algorithm was found that solves the isomorphism problem between $\text{GI}$ graphs in time $2^{O(\log^c(n))}$ for permanent certain $1 < c.$
Reminder:

the language $\text{GI} = \{\langle _1, _2 \rangle∶ _1 \text{ is isomorphic to } _2\}$
the language $\text{GNI} = \{\langle _1, _2 \rangle∶ _1 \text{ is NOT isomorphic to } _2\}$

As for, the graphs in the above context are not directed.
In this scenario we will imagine that someone proved two more "truths" and we will understand their consequences:

There exists $1 < c$, for which this is the most efficient algorithm for deciding $\text{GI}$ (that is, a lower barrier)
$\text{3SAT}\leq_p \text{GI}$

One question in my mind that under these two additional "truths" (assumptions), is there  a deterministic algorithm that operates in time $2^{O(\log^c(n))}$ , which given the $\text{CNF}$ formula (not necessarily $\text{3CNF}$) returns a satisfying assignment if one exists and $0$-otherwise?

Assumption 1 does nothing. If the reduction from SAT to GI gives a GI instance of size $\mathcal{O}(n^d)$ (where $d$ is a constant), then you get a complexity of $2^{O(\log^c(n^d))}=2^{O(\log^{c}(n))}$.

@caduk thank you for your reply, would you elaborate more, would you kindly extend your comment into an answer with elaboration?

Assumption 1 does nothing because all we need is the algorithm's existence, not its optimality.
If $GI$ is $NP$-hard, a polynomial reduction exists from $SAT$ to $GI$. Suppose the reduction from SAT to GI gives a GI instance of size $\mathcal{O}(p(n))$ (where $p$ is a polynomial). In that case, you get a complexity of $2^{O(\log^c(p(n)))}$ (this is the complexity for solving the obtained $GI$ instance, the polynomial complexity for building the instance).
Since $\mathcal{O}(\ln(p(n))) = \mathcal{O}(\ln(n))$, the complexity is simply $2^{O(\log^{c}(n))}$ (with the same exponent $c$).
